# Git hooks for metadata storage/retrieval

Tags: git, metadata

One of git's unavoidable quirks is its inability to store and retrieve metadata about a file. For example, on the mac, labels are stored with "extended attributes" (accessible with `xattr`), and any checkout/reset/merge/pull command will erase those attributes if the file is affected by the checkout.

I've looked around to see if someone has written metadata-saving scripts already, but I came up dry.

So what I'd like to do is use Git's hook system to:

1. Read extended attributes when files are committed,
2. Write the attributes to a file stored in the repository that also gets committed,
3. Apply the extended attributes to files that are modified in a merge/checkout/reset.

Which of the hooks should I use? Are `post-receive` and `pre-commit` all that I need? Can `pre-commit` also add a file to the commit (i.e., after writing the new attributes)?

Comment: Why the downvote? If the question is unsatisfactory, leave a comment so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*gibak* tool](http://github.com/mfp/gibak) uses `pre-commit` and `post-checkout` to let its *ometastore* tool save/restore metadata (optionally including xattrs).

You do not want `post-receive`. It is run on the remote end of pushes. It runs for bare repositories, so it has no business trying to update any files from the contents of a pushed commit. Do it in `post-checkout` where you know you will have a working tree available.

Comment: post-merge is also one that should be used. See githooks(5) http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Comment: @Seth Johnson: good catch. You could have `post-merge` do the same kind of work as `post-checkout` to rebuild any metadata that was lost when the merge rewrote files. Merging metadata might be tricky though, depending on how your chosen tools stores it and makes it available for viewing/diffing.

Comment: If anyone else is interested in such a tool as gibak, Slug ( https://github.com/hbaragar/slug ) looks like it is a more-recently maintained fork of gibak with the ability to backup to a remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

[`metastore`](https://github.com/przemoc/metastore) is able to save and restore file metadata, storing it in a separate file (which you can include in your commits)