# How to establish a description for each file in git?

Tags: git

In most SCM systems (e.g. PTC Integrity, ClearCase) it is possible to have a description for each managed file as a kind of metadata.

The description can hold information like project, customer variant etc. and is necessary to fullfill normative standards.

Sure, this information can be put in the header of a source file - but how can I get this with binary files? Is there a way to get this in git?

Comment: How about tracking an extra file which contains the info for every other tracked files?

Comment: Why would you need info on stuff like project and customer variant? In git those things are usually handled by branches or forks.

Comment: ... is necessary to fullfill normative standards ..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing exactly like this. So you probably would have to use additional file(s) as suggested in comments. Also there is semi-official way to add medatada to git commits in form of:

```
<tag>: <info>
```

For example, "`Signed-off-by: User <user@example.com>`". You could use that in a form of, for example, "`X-FileDescription (<path>): <description>`", and use command:

```
git log --fixed-strings --grep="X-FileDescription (<path>)" --max-count=1
```

to find the last version of the description for a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin support but nothing prevents you from simply adding a set of commit hooks to your repo to manage automatic checking in/out of some type of database of metadata and/or creating separate metadata-files with similar names.

Maybe these links can be of interest to you:

- [Git hooks for metadata storage/retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342432/git-hooks-for-metadata-storage-retrieval)
- http://git-annex.branchable.com/

Otherwise, unless it's plain text/source files, there is probably metadata fields in whatever format the version-controlled files themselves are in. The `<tag>: <info>`-answer here is also one valid approach.